# HTTP client receives status code 200 when server panics with gin-gonic and gin-contrib/gzip

Tags: go, go-gin

When accessing the `gin-gonic` server below, the HTTP client should receive the code 500, but receives the code 200.

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/gin-contrib/gzip"
    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
)

func main() {
    gin.SetMode(gin.ReleaseMode)
    r := gin.New()
    r.Use(gin.Logger())
    r.Use(gin.Recovery())
    r.Use(gzip.Gzip(gzip.DefaultCompression))

    r.POST("/test", func(c *gin.Context) {
        panic("test")                        // Server panic and client should receive code 500.
    })

    r.Run(":8080")
}
```

When accessing `/test` from a HTTP client, the go server log is as below and looks return the code 500.

```
[GIN] 2020/09/28 - 10:23:14 | 500 |     67.2995ms |             ::1 | POST     "/test"

2020/09/28 10:23:14 [Recovery] 2020/09/28 - 10:23:14 panic recovered:
test
C:/path/to/myproject/main.go:16 (0x8f193f)
    main.func1: panic("test")
```

But HTTP client receives the code 200.

[image]

When I remove `r.Use(gzip.Gzip(gzip.DefaultCompression))`, the HTTP client receives the code 500.

Why the client receives code 200 with `r.Use(gzip.Gzip(gzip.DefaultCompression))`, How can I fix this?

Comment: I couldn't reproduce this. Getting code 500 with and without the gzip middleware.

Comment: @LLawliet which version are you using? I use go 1.14.6, gin 1.6.3, gin-contrib/gzip 0.0.3

Comment: go 1.15.2, gin 1.6.3, gin-contrib/gzip 0.0.3

Comment: I tried go 1.15.2, but still gets code 200.

Comment: How are you executing the POST? It's probably my fault for using curl without accept headers.

Comment: I am using Postman

Comment: I mixed up the order of the middlewares and was able to reproduce it.

Comment: You can reproduce this with `-H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip'` (not `Accepting` but `Accept`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding the recovery middleware last seems to fix this.

```golang
package main

import (
    "github.com/gin-contrib/gzip"
    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
)

func main() {
    gin.SetMode(gin.ReleaseMode)
    r := gin.New()
    r.Use(gin.Logger())
    r.Use(gzip.Gzip(gzip.DefaultCompression))
    r.Use(gin.Recovery())

    r.POST("/test", func(c *gin.Context) {
        panic("test")                        // Server panic and client should receive code 500.
    })

    r.Run(":8080")
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I've reproduce your case. Postman got code 200 but the server results 500 instead.

The server will call c.Next() to execute 4 handlers when receive post requests. The sequence is as follow:

```
gin.Logger
gin.Recovery
gzip.Gzip(gzip.DefaultCompression)
your handler
```

Here is gin responseWriter writes response header and it will write header only once.

```
func (w *responseWriter) WriteHeaderNow() {
    if !w.Written() {
        w.size = 0
        w.ResponseWriter.WriteHeader(w.status)
    }
}
```

Both `gzip.Gzip(gzip.DefaultCompression)` and `gin.Recovery` has defer func to write response header. Golang's deferred calls are executed in last-in-first-out order. So `gzip.Gzip(gzip.DefaultCompression)` will write response header to 200, and `gin.Recovery` won't write reponse header to 500 as expected.

So to solve this problem, you should change the order of handlers and make sure `gin.Recovery` is the last handler to load.